# How to mathematically represent my equation?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I want to say "for all k from 1, 2,...B that are not elements of the vector S.  What is the best/most professional way to represent this?  Is there a better way to represent it than

[image]

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Is the question about typesetting, or math notation?

Comment: I'm just looking for help from anyone kind enough to give some advice.  I've gotten a lot of helpful answers about a wide range of topics on this site over the past few months.

Comment: What is the advice you're seeking *about*: is it about math notation, or is it about how to implement a certain notational choice using (La)TeX?

Comment: Some more context is needed; what do you mean by a “vector”? Normally a vector has no elements, so I can't see what `k\notin\mathbf{s}` is supposed to mean.

Comment: `For $k=1,2,\dots,B$, provided $k$ does not appear in the vector $\mathbf{s}$.` Using symbols at any cost is not recommendable.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I should have called S a set of integers rather than a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try

```
for $k\in\{1,2,\dots,B \mid k\not\in \mathbf{s} \}$.
```

[image]

Presumably, `B` is an integer and `\mathbf{s}` is a set of integers ranging from 1 to `B`, right?

Comment: This is one way to disambiguate it.

Comment: Thanks, I really like this notation.  It looks much more professional.

Comment: Sorry, I cat find no sensible mathematical meaning in this notation.

Comment: @egreg - I was hoping the OP would clarify what `k\not\in\mathbf{s}` is supposed to mean.

Comment: You are correct that s is a set of integers and B is a integer

Comment: Just a matter of personal taste: unless you have good reason from elsewhere in the manuscript, I'd use lower case  b for the integer and upper case  S  (perhaps bold) for the set.

Answer (score 2):

Correct would be something like `$1 \le k \le B$, $k \notin S$`. Elipses are ambiguous...

Don't try to reduce everything to symbols, that easily turns into utter gibberish. What you write is for *humans* to *understand*, symbols (particularly less familiar ones) just stand in the way.